# stood vs standing

Tags: past-tense, british-english

I was listening to a podcast and

person 1:

> If you were stood on the station platform?

pedant:

> Standing, if you were standing on the station platform?

What is wrong with stood in that sentence? as a native speaker it sounds perfectly correct to me.

Comment: Not that this issue has never been talked about before but '*on* the train station' seems like the bigger issue with the sentence to me

Comment: @Angelos my search for stood vs standing didn't bring up any results, and as I don't care about the point you raised I edited

Comment: Please note: I have noticed that BrE has somewhat different uses for the verbs sit and stand. For example: **I was sat by the back door.** is OK in BrE but not necessarily in AmE as we would say: sitting. Angelos: you stand **on a platform**.

Comment: @Lambie it originally said "stood on the train station" so i edited that bit out.

Comment: The issue is this: Do BrE speakers say or do they not say: stood on the station platform *for* standing on the station platform?

Comment: I would say stood, everyone I know would say stood, but we also say less instead of fewer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To put it simply, 'stood' is the **past participle** of the verb 'stand', and in formal English we would use it when someone stood you somewhere - 'the girl stood the doll by the toy basket' If you were stood on the station, in standard formal English that means someone told you to stand on the station (presumably until you were *moved*).

In some British regional dialects, certainly in the Bristol area where I live, this non-standard usage is very common - I was stood at the bus stop, I was sat at the table. They also say 'I was *led* (laid) down in bed'.

The standard English way to describe a position or posture is to use some form of the verb 'to be' (e.g. am, was, will be, etc) followed by the **present participle** of the verb, e.g. I am standing by the door, I am sitting at the table, I will be lying in bed.

Comment: A lot of my childhood dialect turns out to be from Bath where dad's family come from, that could be why it sounds so natural to me.

Comment: @WendyG - they say it in Keynsham!

Comment: My friend and I always smile when someone says "I was sat [somewhere]." We can both imagine our late mothers correcting them - "_Sitting._"

Comment: It's also common in Yorkshire, where I live.

Comment: Aren't there dialects where _both_ would be common, e.g. “I was sat sitting there…”?

Comment: @gidds - have seen 'sat sitting' reported in northern English dialects, including Manchester. I have seen it described as 'something Nellie Pledge would have said'. Nellie was a character played by the comic actress Hylda Baker, in a UK TV series 'Nearest and Dearest' (1968 - 1973) which was set in Colne, Lancashire, which is also in the North West.

Comment: @gidds - update... I asked my wife, who comes from Wigan in Lancashire, which is in Greater Manchester. not all that far from Colne, either, and she says 'Nobody talks like that nowadays, maybe my grandparents might have'. Several forum comments I found said 'My granny said it'.

Comment: It could also be the past tense, in which case it may have developed from both "was" and "stand" being put in the past tense.

Answer (score 3):

**If you were stood** is not grammatically wrong, but it is almost certainly not what the speaker intended, because *stood* is the past participle of *stand*.

**If you were *present-participle***: you were performing the action.  Think about "If you were eating".

**If you were *past-participle***: someone else was performing the action on you.  Think about "If you were eaten".

So staying "If you were stood" means "If *somebody else* placed you there in an upright position"!  That's almost certainly not what the speaker meant.

Comment: I am sure this it totally correct and will be very useful to one of the learners on this site,  it might mean something to them, but it went whoosh over my head.

Comment: Unless they were speaking one of the many regional dialects in which it is perfectly normal and therefore grammatical in that dialect